# Firstchild/lastchild not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wonder, why in this situation "firstChild" and "lastChild" is not working, but when I'm doing this by the position of li in the array, everything works just fine.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my JS, when it's not working:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
      div[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        var list = this.firstElementChild;
        var listLi = list.children;

        var firstLi = listLi.firstChild;
        var lastLi = listLi.lastChild;

        firstLi.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        lastLi.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      });
};
```

I was trying to do this like this, and it's not working:

```
listLi.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "red";
listLi.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

but when I'm doing it with position in the array, everything works just fine:

```
listLi[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
listLi[4].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

edit: it looks like that, when it's working: https://fiddle.jshell.net/aadfnazk/

Comment: can u show us some fiddle with your code?

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not working*? Does it output any errors?

Comment: `firstChild` and `lastChild` are for an element, not a children list. You do not need `listLi`, just use `list.firstChild` directly.

Comment: @Junior I've put some fiddle, what it should look like, when it works.

Comment: I've done it with the suggestion of the @rgthree and should it look like this? https://fiddle.jshell.net/sjkyey37/ it's not working

Comment: @tresdin that's the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must use `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` so that it selects an element node instead of a text node.

Second, call them on the `list` element instead of the `listLi` children array.

```
list.firstElementChild.style.backgroundColor = "red";
list.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aadfnazk/1/)